# Accessing private members with reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I know how to access std::string in class S, but how can i get int i in this class? What should i do? I understand i should shift the pointer, but in what way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class S {
    std::string s = "abcd";
    int i = 9;
};


int main() {
    
    S s;

    auto* f = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(&s);
    
    std::cout << *f;

    return 0;
}
```

i tried something like

`auto* f = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s); f += sizeof(std::string("abcd");`

but it didn't work (i know it even looks silly but i tried >-< )

Comment: which struct? There's only a class.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to. That is the point of `private`. `&S()` is also not valid C++.

Comment: `&S()` is a non-standard MSVC extension, I believe. `S()` is an rvalue, and you shouldn't be able to take an address of one. Even if it works on your compiler, the temporary `S` object is destroyed immediately, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

Comment: There is no way to do that without invoking Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Your attempt looks ok to me. You forgot the closing `)`, and you need to `reinterpret_cast` the resulting pointer to `int *` before dereferencing it. Also note that `sizeof(std::string("..."))` is the same as `sizeof(std::string)`. The value of a class doesn't affect its size, which is fixed at compile time.

Comment: perhaps if you explain what you are trying to achieve a better option will become clear - I am almost certain what you are attempting is not a good idea :p

Comment: (a) the code does not compile - live - https://godbolt.org/z/fx19n7oTc ;  (b) fixing the compilation error ( https://godbolt.org/z/Y3sohvsGP ) result in Undefined Behaviour as `S` and `std::string` are not related types.  See [Type aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen there are a lot of ways to legally access private members of class/struct, the access specifier only applies to the name (not the actual peace of memory).

Comment: @RichardCritten it's valid code, as long as `S` is standard-layout (but `std::string` may not guarantee to be one (then also `S`)).

Comment: yes, &S() is not valid, there should be S s; &s

Comment: I know i shouldn't be able to access private members but bruuuuh, it's C++. If i want, i will be able to :)

Comment: @Dmitry hi! could you pls elaborate a little bit more on ways of legally accessing private data?

Answer (score -4):

So, the answer is:

```
S s;

auto* f = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(&s);

int* ii = reinterpret_cast<int*>(f + 1);

std::cout << *ii;
```

Thanks everyone for attention, hope this will help someone ;)

Comment: And then it will turn out compiler added padding between `s` and `i` and your code won't work anymore.

Comment: This is Undefined Behaviour as `S` and `int` are not related types.

Comment: @RichardCritten the same as program behaviour without `std::launder`. it says it is undefined but it's actually not (imao)